# Resizable jquery with maps not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 nested divs and i would like the "maps" to be resizable, however the code just doesn't seem to work for me after various looking here on stack. Any possible ideas why i cant see the "n" handles to expand to 70% of the parent?
Heres my [fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/r1mf51ke/1/)

html

```
<div class="content" id="wrapper">
 <div class="search-div" id="search">
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  <h4>Heading</h4>
  </div>
 <div class="maps" id="maps">
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#maps").resizable({
  handles: "n",
  maxHeight: "70%",
  minHeight: "30%"
});
```

Comment: What is `n` in the `handles: "n"` part?

Comment: the north handle @MarcosPérezGude

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var map;
var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.004558, 77.6017),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       mapOptions);

$("#maps").css("height", "120px");
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/r1mf51ke/2/)

Comment: It needs to be resizable, not to trigger a resize event.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what i am looking for, I am trying to resize the div with the jquery resizable UI. Perhaps this is for the maps specificically